# Custom odoo module - how to make a table

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am creating a custom module with additional part numbers on a separate tab in the products screen. I have built the module, but am having trouble figuring out how to display the information so it matches the layout in the attached image. I have tried tree view but have not been able to get the fields on the same line. Can this only be accomplished through css or is there a table view that I am not aware of?

I also need to make sure that all of the information in row 1 stays tethered together for additional forms, etc. My plan is to make the field names for each row end with a different number (i.e. x_mfrname1,x_mfrpn1,x_mfrname2,x_mfrpn2, etc.). Can somebody please just tell me if I am on the right track. This is the initial Odoo setup for a client of mine and I don't want them to come back to me down the line and find out I forgot something. I have been scouring the internet and reading a few books but I am not completely confident.

Here is a link to a layout of what I am talking about:
[MFG Part Number Tab](http://project5longbeach.com/images/Odoo%20MFG%20Part%20Detail.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class sub_part_details(models.Model)
    _name='sub.part.detail'

    primary_pn=fields.Boolean('Primary P/N')
    obsolete=fields.Boolean('Obsolete')
    pn=fields.Char('P/N')
    desc=fields.Char('Description')
    upgrade=fields.Char('Upgrade')
    part_detail_id=fields.Many2one('part.details')

class part_details(models.Model)
    _name='part.details'

    cat=fields.Char('CAT')
    sub_ass=fields.Char('Subassembly')
    main_ass=fields.Char('Main Assembly')
    notes=fields.Text('Notes')
    sub_details_ids=fields.One2Many(''sub.part.detail','part_detail_id')
```

It might be helpful

Comment: Thank you! Each line of the sub part detail will be considered one entry and I need to make sure all of the entries on each line stays connected for use on other forms and reports. What is the best way to do that? I was going to make each field end with a different number (primary_pn1, obsolete1, pn1 ... primary_pn2, obsolete2, pn2, etc). So if I need to pull all of the information from one line and have it appear on a form or a report I can get pn1, and all of the other fields that end with the number 1. Is that the most efficient way to do that or is there another way?

Comment: parent table contain ids of child tables.

Comment: So I should make the pn field be the main table and then all of the other fields the sub_part_details?

Comment: I keep getting an error trying to install the module: " Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition Error details:
Field `x_bomcategory` does not exist" from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class product_part_detail(osv.Model):
    _name = 'product.part.detail'
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    _columns = {
 'x_mfrpn': fields.char('P/N'),
        'product_part_detail': fields.one2many('sub.part.detail','product_part_detail')
 }

Comment: class sub_part_detail(osv.Model):
    _name = 'sub.part.detail'
    _inherit = 'product.part.detail'

    _columns = {
        'x_bomcategory': fields.char('Category'),
 'x_primarypn': fields.boolean('Primary PN'),
 'x_obsolete': fields.boolean('Obsolete'),
 'x_mfrname': fields.char('MFR'),
 'x_pndescription': fields.char('Description'),
 'x_pnupgrade': fields.char('Upgrade'),
 'x_pnnotes': fields.text('Notes'),
        'sub_part_detail': fields.many2one('product.part.detail')
 }